# Determine which pin has been selected on a map for segue

Tags: ios, mapkit, pushpin, callout

Mapkit usage, here is my scenario: When the user chooses one of the pushpins on my map, then selects the callout associated with that pin, the user is to be be brought to another ViewController that will show information pertinent to their selection.

To set data for the destinationViewController, I am using

```
   prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

This is working but I have an issue where I am not sure which annotation has been selected.
The following code illustrates my issue - the code works, but I have it hard coded to "objectAtIndex:0" instead of objectAtIndex:"whatever pin they selected"

```
    [self.myImageViewController setAddressMessage:  [[self.annotations objectAtIndex:0] houseAddress]];
```

In prepareForSegue, how do I know which pin they have selected?

Comment: If I put a breakpoint in I can see that "sender" is a different hex value depending on which pin/callout was selected, I need appropriate code to relate that value to an annotation and use it as an index for my array.

Comment: And prior to this I have called  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"My Image" sender:control]; so it is the control value I need to utilize, but how do I relate it to an index for my array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not knowing the rest of your code, I'm not sure if this will work but this is how I found the annotation in a similar situation where a button on the annotation view's callout was pressed.

```
-(void)buttonInCalloutWasTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    if ([[[[button superview] superview] class] isSubclassOfClass:[MKAnnotationView class]]) {
        MKAnnotation *annotation = [(MKPinAnnotationView *)[[button superview] superview] annotation];
        [self.myImageViewController setAddressMessage:  [annotation houseAddress]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You.  This worked with just a small tweak for my code.          MYAnnotation *localannotations = [(MKPinAnnotationView *)[[sender superview] superview] annotation];